# Thank you for my part / share

Tags: phrase-choice

I was wondering which choice below makes my sentence sound natural. In case none of them works here, then I wonder how shall I phrase it in proper English?

> - I have no word to express my gratitude.
>   Thank you very much ....... and on behalf of Sarah.

a. for my part 
b. for my share

**For my (or his, her, etc.) part:**

Oxford:

> Used to focus attention on one person or group and distinguish them from others involved in asituation:

- for my part I was glad when the end of September came.

Comment: In this context _on my part_ would be better.

Comment: I don't really like "on my part" here, because it distinguishes you from others - saying "for my part, I was glad" implies that other people *weren't* glad!  So I would not use it if you're talking about being grateful, because it implies other people are not grateful!

Comment: Well @stangdon, may I know what would you say instead? I.e. how would you phrase it?

Comment: You could just say "I thank you for myself and for Sarah", to make it clear that you are speaking for both you and her.

Comment: Well @stangdon. Thank you very much for the response, just out of curiosity, I wonder if I could I say: "I thank you for myself and on behalf of Sarah"?